# Tag wiki exerpt-excerpts — can we choose the cut point?

Tags: feature-request, tag-wikis

There appears to be a feature in the new tag page where text preceding the first "is" or "are" in the first sentence is omitted.

This makes sense for saving space when the first part of the excerpt is just repeating the tag name, but often useful information is lost. For example, for [equipment-recommendation](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equipment-recommendation), we had "Please note that this is not a general camera-recommendation site.", which got chopped awkwardly. Changing "is not" to "isn't" is the work-around there, but obviously it's a kludge.

Another problematic example is [lightroom](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lightroom), where the fact that this refers to Adobe Lightroom is a crucial fact. Since the excerpt begins "Adobe Lightroom is....", that gets lost. The excerpt could be rephrased to "Lightroom is the name of a product by Adobe which...", but that's *longer*.

Or [lighting](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lighting), where "At its core, photography is nothing but the recording of light." becomes "nothing but the recording of light."

It'd be nice to have one of:

- excerpts were only chopped if they match the tag name, or
- excerpts could be marked as "please don't chop the beginning", or
- the chop-point could be explicitly marked with some sort of inline tag.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections, Jay. See, now, if it weren't clipped, I might more easily remember if it's Apple or Adobe. :)

Answer (score 1):

This only happens if the is/are is in the first 40 characters, so reprhase it, or trigger the clip earlier by saying something like "This tag is.."

Currently this is the regex that we use for shortening:

```
   @"^.{0,40}?
        (
        (this\stag\s(is)?\s?)  # this tag .. this tag is|about ...
        |
        (used\sto\s)           # this tag is used to ...
        |
        (the\s[^\s]+\stag\s)   # the {foo} tag ...
        |
        (the\stag\s[^\s]+)     # the tag {foo} ...
        |
        (\s(is|are)\s)         # blah blah blah is|are ...
        )"
```

Comment: Okay, I will. But having to keep considerations like this in mind work against the goal of having each tag wiki excerpt be _awesome_.

Comment: @matt I updated with the actual regex, so either match or avoid one of those patterns. Note the {0,40} means "only do this in the first 40 chars"